# Remove an inline width style setting with CSS

Tags: css

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="wtHolder" style="width:41.66%; height:150px; position:relative;">
```

**Is there something I can add in css for the `wtHolder` class that will remove `width:41.66%` of this?**

(If you want the background of why I need to do this, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38750702/16241).)

Comment: Have you tried the oft maligned `!important`?

Comment: @j08691 - I did.  This got me close: `.wtHolder {width: auto !important;}`   (I did not know about the `auto` option.)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use !important to overwrite it:

```
.wtHolder {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a trick , but you can actually use `!important`

```css
.wtHolder{
  width:100% !important;
  background-color:black
}
```

```html
<div class="wtHolder" style="width:41.66%; height:150px; position:relative;">
```